# init == SysVinit?

Tags: linux

Я запутался в этом зверинце систем инициализации.

init — это эквивалент SysVinit?

Comment: SysVinit это просто разновидность init для систем - наследников архитектуры System V. так что можно сказать что и равно. Хотя думаю при желании можно init и от BSD и от OSF/1 прикрутить

Comment: Скорее ⊃, чем ==.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`init=/путь/к/файлу` — это всего лишь [один из параметров](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt) программы *linux*, указывающий, какой файл надо будет запустить по окончании процесса инициализации самой программы *linux* (собственно, это практически единственное (помимо распаковки initrd и монтирования корневой ф.с.) и последнее «активное» действие, которое выполняет программа *linux*). с этого момента, можно сказать, и начинается работа *операционной системы*.

по умолчанию этот параметр равен `/sbin/init`.

*sysv-init* (правильнее, вероятно, говорить [*sysv-style init*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init#SysV-style)) — это лишь один из «стилей» инициализации операционной системы. есть, конечно, разные реализации этого «стиля». а есть и иные «стили».

---

конкретизируя: нет, параметр программы *linux* под названием *init* — это **не** *sysv-style init*.

---

типичная реализация *sysv-style init*, используемая, например, в пакете [*sysvinit*](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=sysvinit&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all) в *debian*-основных дистрибутивах — это проект [System V style init programs](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/sysvinit).

типичные реализации иных стилей — это [upstart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstart), [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) и т.д. и т.п.; многие перечислены в [вики-статье init](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init#Replacements_for_init).

Comment: А какие есть реализации этого стиля?
Что такое тогда upstart и systemd?

Comment: @Сергей systemd это система инициализации, пришедшая на смену init system v

Comment: @Сергей и раз уж на то пошло, вики:
init (сокращение от англ. initialization — инициализация) — __система инициализации__ в UNIX и Unix-подобных системах, которая запускает все остальные процессы. Работает как демон и обычно имеет PID 1. Обычно (согласно Filesystem Hierarchy Standard) располагается по пути /sbin/init.

Comment: @jumpjet67 я читал вики. Меня заинтересовал другой вопрос. После прочтения этой  статьи https://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=42206 , мне стало любопытно что такое Upstart и sysvinit. Информацию про Upstart нашел сразу, а по поводу sysvinit однозначности не было

Comment: @Сергей, upstart и systemd — это явно другие «стили». в частности, насколько мне известно, у них нет деления на *runlevel*-ы. по поводу разных реализаций — насколько я знаю (и глядя на список в вики-статье), весьма соответствуют этому стилю как минимум busybox-init и initng.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin у systemd есть всё те же уровни запуска, просто реализованы иначе. В частности,  runlevel на ubuntu 16.04 даёт `N 5` - то есть пятый уровень запуска.

Comment: @jumpjet67 мне еще интересно вот что. Ubuntu 14.04 поддерживает sysvinit и upstart. С 15 версии Ubuntu перешла на systemd. Если я, к примеру, разработчик и написал свою программу которая должна работать как сервис, то теперь мне придется узнавать на какой версии ubuntu я запущен и использовать разные системы инициализации?

Comment: @jumpjet67, насколько я знаю, это всего лишь «мимикрия под *sysv*».

Comment: @Сергей думайте о init в ОС linux как о системе инициализации, работающей по канонам, задоженным ещё в Unix SysV, и от того иногда называемый init SysV. Иные системы инициализации (systemd, upstart) этим канонам уже не следуют.

Comment: @Сергей задачи запуска демонов (не сервисов, если речь о linux) как раз и ложится на систему инициализации, вам лишь нужно проработать функционал. Представьте. помимо вашего демона есть ещё тысячи других. Если бы они отказались работать с новой системой инициализации, она нафиг никому не была бы нужна.

Comment: @Сергей, нет, вам не обязательно выяснять, какая система инициализации используется в данной конкретной установке дистрибутива. создавайте «обыкновенный» sysv-style инициализационный скрипт — этого достаточно. любая «новейшая» система инициализации просто обязана поддерживать работу этих скриптов. иначе слишком много надо переписывать.

Comment: Я вас понял :) А мне еще интересно следующее. У меня Linux Mint 17.3 . У меня используется upstart и init(sysvinit). Насколько я понял в директории /etc/init хранятся config файлы для upstart, в которых есть похожие строки "start on ((filesystem
           and runlevel [!06]
           and started dbus
           and plymouth-ready)
          or runlevel PREVLEVEL=S)"
Эти конфиги создает upstart? откуда он знает что после чего запускать? или эти конфиги создавались разрабами ПО конкретного демона?

Comment: @Сергей, задайте новый вопрос, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом верхнем углу страницы.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответы :)

Comment: @Сергей я для наших приложений написал запуски под любой вкус - CentOS до 6: sysv-style-init `/etc/init.d`, Ubuntu до 15: upstart `/etc/init`, Ubuntu после 15: systemd `/etc/systemd/system`. Для развертывания используется Ansible в котором есть переменная `ansible_service_mgr`. Нашим разработчика всеравно какая из систем используется, а DevOps отделу нет