# Upstart init system

Tags: linux

У меня Linux Mint 17.3. У меня используется upstart и init(sysvinit).

Насколько я понял, в директории /etc/init/ хранятся конфигурационные файлы для upstart, в которых есть похожие строки:

> start on ((filesystem and runlevel [!06] and started dbus and plymouth-ready) or runlevel PREVLEVEL=S)

Эти конфиги создает upstart? откуда он знает что после чего запускать? или эти конфиги создавались разработчиками конкретного демона?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Эти конфиги создает upstart или эти конфиги создавались разрабами конкретного демона?

если вы посмотрите на принадлежность пакетам файлов из этого каталога:

```
$ dpkg -S /etc/init/*
...
at: /etc/init/atd.conf
...
```

то увидите, что принадлежат они разным пакетам. например, файл `/etc/init/atd.conf` принадлежит пакету `at`. соответственно, создавался он либо разработчиком, либо мэйнтэйнером пакета `at`.

> откуда он знает что после чего запускать?

на основании директив внутри файлов. в частности, например, так: `start on starting другой-сервис` — данный сервис будет запущен после запуска `другого-сервиса`.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/518181/init-sysvinit#comment635650_518199

Получается разработчик демона должен учитывать init system

Comment: @Сергей Разработчик пакета не обязан. Есть те кто готовит пакеты для включения в конкретные дистрибутивы linux. Это может быть как разработчик пакета, так и люди занимающиеся сборкой дистрибутива.

Comment: @Сергей, в пакет `at` в дистрибутиве *ubuntu* входит и `/etc/init/файл` и `/etc/init.d/файл`. я проверил — действительно, при удалении `/etc/init/файл` *upstart* не вызывает `/etc/init.d/файл`. ну, значит, вот такой он «кривой», этот *upstart*, раз не поддерживает обратную совместимость с *sysv-style*-скриптами. тот же *systemd*, насколько мне известно, отлично поддерживает. и, да, как верно отметил Mike, это уже проблемы мэйнтэйнера пакета, а не разработчика программы.

Comment: @Сергей, нет, не настолько «крив» *upstart*. в пакет входит скрипт `/etc/init/rc.conf`, с помощью которого и запускаются необходимые при «переходе» (в случае upstart это, скорее, эмуляция) с одного runlevel-а на другой *sysv-style*-скрипты. почему у меня не стартовал *atd* — это уже надо разбираться.

Comment: Он не запустился потому что у Вас скорее всего отсутствует atd в  /etc/rcN.d . Как сказано в rc.conf 

"This task runs the old System V-style rc script when changing between runlevels"

. Также в этом rc.conf следующее:

*/etc/init.d/rc $RUNLEVEL*

. А в /etc/init.d/rc имеется вот это:

*for s in /etc/rc$runlevel.d/K**

Значит, если для демона отсутствует .conf файл upstart-а, тогда upstart смотрит его в  /etc/rcN.d директориях. Если и там нету тогда демон и не запустится.